# Postgres query to replace CTE query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like below

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>SELECT * FROM review.tbl_school_review</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>review_id</th>
            <th>school_id</th>
            <th>dept_id</th>
            <th>contact_id</th>
            <th>rating</th>
            <th>comment</th>
            <th>review_closed</th>
            <th>created_when</th>
            <th>modified_when</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>cdaa36be-703c-493a-adbc-093e0b438d64</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>4d811902-acce-448f-9fa8-c48404202f34</td>
            <td>776f41c8-727a-4318-a304-815d804dcaa7</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>good</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2020-01-11 18:58:34</td>
            <td>2020-01-11 18:58:34</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2f858144-1598-4179-ab69-96caa67bcc56</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>4d811902-acce-448f-9fa8-c48404202f34</td>
            <td>776f41c8-727a-4318-a304-815d804dcaa7</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>2020-01-11 19:00:02</td>
            <td>2020-01-11 19:00:02</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>cf7be564-fe3f-4961-8a99-5c14f540693f</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>4d811902-acce-448f-9fa8-c48404202f34</td>
            <td>776f41c8-727a-4318-a304-815d804dcaa7</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>2020-01-11 19:00:33</td>
            <td>2020-01-11 19:00:33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a2ba8acc-01cf-45fd-a187-fb7dbbd9abe6</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>5cf9f961-baab-4359-a579-5f4f262c7903</td>
            <td>cd7b19a5-5c7b-462b-91d8-6c288ff63968</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>2020-01-11 19:01:52</td>
            <td>2020-01-11 19:01:52</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>f7809e23-6fd8-4e3c-9098-38968ec5d194</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>5cf9f961-baab-4359-a579-5f4f262c7903</td>
            <td>cd7b19a5-5c7b-462b-91d8-6c288ff63968</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>2020-01-11 19:02:17</td>
            <td>2020-01-11 19:02:17</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to create a function in postgres that will take school_id and an array of dept_ids  as parameters and it should return the rating and comment against the dept. If there are any closed review for a dept, the query should return the comment and rating from the closed review. If there are no closed reviews it will return rating and comment as null

So the result of the query should be the below

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>SELECT * FROM review.ftm_list_dept_review('{"4d811902-acce-448f-9fa8-c48404202f34","5cf9f961-baab-4359-a579-5f4f262c7903", "0ef7312c-09a4-46af-b694-a14618664a74"}'::uuid[],100)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>school_id</th>
            <th>dept_id</th>
            <th>rating</th>
            <th>review_comment</th>
            <th>review_completed</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>100</td>
            <td>4d811902-acce-448f-9fa8-c48404202f34</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>good</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>5cf9f961-baab-4359-a579-5f4f262c7903</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I created a function like the below and it works fine , I read that CTE are bad for performance in postgres. is there any other way of getting the result without using a cte.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION review.ftm_list_dept_review(
             IN param_dept_id  UUID[]
            ,IN param_school_id      INT

)RETURNS TABLE(
         school_id INT
        ,dept_id UUID
        ,rating INT
        ,review_comment TEXT
        ,review_completed INT)

AS $function$

BEGIN
        RETURN query

        WITH cte_closed_review_details AS(

            SELECT   COALESCE(ar.rating,0) AS rating
                    ,COALESCE(COMMENT,' ') AS review_comment
                    ,ud.dept_id AS dept_id
                    ,COALESCE(ar.review_closed,0) AS review_completed
            FROM    (SELECT unnest(param_dept_id ::UUID[] ) AS dept_id) AS ud
                    LEFT JOIN  review.tbl_school_review ar ON ud.dept_id = ar.dept_id AND ar.review_closed = 1  AND ar.school_id = param_school_id 
        )
        SELECT
                ar.school_id        
                ,crd.dept_id    
                ,crd.rating         
                ,crd.review_comment 
                ,crd.review_completed :: INT    
        FROM    cte_closed_review_details crd 
                INNER JOIN  review.tbl_school_review ar  ON crd.dept_id = ar.dept_id  AND ar.school_id = param_school_id
        WHERE   1=1
        GROUP BY ar.school_id,crd.dept_id,crd.rating,crd.review_comment,crd.review_completed;

END
$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER;

 /*

 SELECT * FROM  review.ftm_list_dept_review('{"4d811902-acce-448f-9fa8-c48404202f34","5cf9f961-baab-4359-a579-5f4f262c7903", "0ef7312c-09a4-46af-b694-a14618664a74"}'::uuid[],100);
*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS review.tbl_school_review
(
     review_id              UUID                NOT NULL
    ,school_id              INT                 NOT NULL
    ,dept_id                UUID                NOT NULL
    ,contact_id             UUID                NOT NULL
    ,rating                 SMALLINT            CONSTRAINT df_review_rating DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
    ,comment                TEXT                CONSTRAINT df_review_comment DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
    ,review_closed          SMALLINT            CONSTRAINT df_review_closed DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
    ,created_when           TIMESTAMP           CONSTRAINT df_review_created_datetime DEFAULT (now() at time zone 'utc') NOT NULL
    ,modified_when          TIMESTAMP           CONSTRAINT df_review_modified_datetime DEFAULT (now() at time zone 'utc') NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT pk_school_review_schoolid_deptid_contactid_createdwhen PRIMARY KEY (school_id, dept_id,contact_id,created_when)
    ,CONSTRAINT un_school_review_review_id UNIQUE (review_id) 
);

INSERT INTO review.tbl_school_review (review_id,school_id,dept_id,contact_id,rating,COMMENT,review_closed)
VALUES (
'cdaa36be-703c-493a-adbc-093e0b438d64'::UUID
,100::int
,'4d811902-acce-448f-9fa8-c48404202f34'::UUID
,'776f41c8-727a-4318-a304-815d804dcaa7'::UUID
,1::INT
,'good'::TEXT
,1::integer
);

INSERT INTO review.tbl_school_review (review_id,school_id,dept_id,contact_id)
VALUES (
'2f858144-1598-4179-ab69-96caa67bcc56'::UUID
,100::int
,'4d811902-acce-448f-9fa8-c48404202f34'::UUID
,'776f41c8-727a-4318-a304-815d804dcaa7'::UUID

);

INSERT INTO review.tbl_school_review (review_id,school_id,dept_id,contact_id)
VALUES (
'cf7be564-fe3f-4961-8a99-5c14f540693f'::UUID
,100::int
,'4d811902-acce-448f-9fa8-c48404202f34'::UUID
,'776f41c8-727a-4318-a304-815d804dcaa7'::UUID

);


INSERT INTO review.tbl_school_review (review_id,school_id,dept_id,contact_id)
VALUES (
'a2ba8acc-01cf-45fd-a187-fb7dbbd9abe6'::UUID
,100::int
,'5cf9f961-baab-4359-a579-5f4f262c7903'::UUID
,'cd7b19a5-5c7b-462b-91d8-6c288ff63968'::UUID

);

INSERT INTO review.tbl_school_review (review_id,school_id,dept_id,contact_id)
VALUES (
'f7809e23-6fd8-4e3c-9098-38968ec5d194'::UUID
,100::int
,'5cf9f961-baab-4359-a579-5f4f262c7903'::UUID
,'cd7b19a5-5c7b-462b-91d8-6c288ff63968'::UUID

);

SELECT * FROM review.tbl_school_review ;
```

Comment: How much data do you have if you have to worry about CTE performance? Did you try to generate test data and what kind of execution times did you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just replace it with a subquery (place the CTE definition in brackets after `from` before `inner join`), but CTEs don't necessarily have bad performance